# 3次元のLSTMのやりかたがわからない

Tags: python

以下のようなデータと正解データがあり、これをLSTMで学習したいのですが3次元と1次元を計算しようとしてもエラーが発生してしまいます。
どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

**対象のデータ:**

```py
# 3次元
data = [[[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]], [[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]]]
# 1次元
answer = [1.0, 2.0]

# [[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]]を入力すると1.0が返ってくるようにしたい
```

**エラー内容:**

```
File "c:/Users/zunda/Desktop/Chainer_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation/test.py", line 92, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential: expected shape=(None, None, 2), found shape=[None, 2, 3]
```

**ソースコード:**

```py
x_train = np.array(data)
y_train = np.array(answer)

x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
y_train = y_train.reshape((y_train.shape[0]))

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 2)))
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初のレイヤーの入力次元が `(3,2)` ですが、実際には `(2,3)` の入力を渡しています。

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

# 3次元
data = [[[0.4, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]], [[0.4, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]]]
# 1次元
answer = [1.0, 2.0]

x_train = np.array(data)
y_train = np.array(answer)

print(x_train.shape)  # (2, 2, 3): サンプル数2, 次元 (2, 3)

x_train = x_train.reshape(
    (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
y_train = y_train.reshape((y_train.shape[0]))

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 3)))  # 合わせる
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
```

これでとりあえずエラーは出なくなるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーが出なくなりました。次にmodel.predictをしたのですが、そちらもうまくいきません。先ほどのコードに追加したものをしたに載せます。

Comment: コードを4行追加したコードを下に載せさせていただきました。

Comment: @zunda 完全に別の質問なので、新規の質問として投稿してください。

Comment: 別で質問させていただきました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73647/40856

Comment: 間違って追加した自分の回答は削除することが出来ます

Comment: 質問が解決した場合はチェックマークを押すと回答者のモチベーションになります

Comment: stackoverflow不慣れですいません。ありがとうございます。