# KerasでLSTMをしようとしているが、エラーが出てしまう。

Tags: python, 機械学習, keras

3次元のデータと1次元の正解データをLSTMで学習させようとしているが、エラーが出てしまします。
どうすればよいでしょうか？
コードに問題があったため少し変更しました。
参考にしたものはこちらです。
http://sweng.web.fc2.com/ja/program/python/time-series-forecast-lstm.html

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed

#3次元
train_value = [[[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]], [[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]]]
# 1次元
train_label_list = [1.0, 2.0]

# [[0.4, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1,0.4]]を入力すると1.0が返ってくるようにしたい

x_train = np.array(train_value)
y_train = np.array(train_label_list)

x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 3)))
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

test_value = [[0.2, 0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.3,0.4]]

x_test = np.array(test_value)
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

yhat = model.predict(x_test)

print(yhat)
```

エラー内容

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential: expected shape=(None, None, 3), found shape=[None, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fit`や`predict`に渡すデータは `(サンプル数, データの次元0, データの次元1, ... データの次元n)` の形で渡します。
今データの次元は `(2, 3)` なので、`shape=(サンプル数, 2, 3)` となるようにします。
`predict`で確認したいサンプルは一つなので、`shape=(1, 2, 3)`です。

なので、

```
test_value = [[0.2, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]]
x_test = np.array(test_value)
print(x_test.shape)  # (2, 3)

x_test = x_test.reshape(1, 2, 3)
print(x_test.shape)  # (1, 2, 3): サンプル数1, 次元 (2, 3)

yhat = model.predict(x_test)
print(yhat)
```

もしくは

```
test_value = [[0.2, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]]
x_test = np.array(test_value)
print(x_test.shape)  # (2, 3)

x_test = x_test[np.newaxis, :, :]
print(x_test.shape)  # (1, 2, 3): サンプル数1, 次元 (2, 3)

yhat = model.predict(x_test)
print(yhat)
```

で通ります。

参考:
[NumPy配列ndarrayに次元を追加するnp.newaxis, np.expand_dims()](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-newaxis/)

`test_value`を直書きしてるなら単に

```
test_value = [[[0.2, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]]]
x_test = np.array(test_value)
print(x_test.shape)  # (1, 2, 3)
```

でもいいです。